# Error in terraform dynamic block for azure resource azurerm_subnet

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following terraform resource declaration

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "main" {
  for_each             = var.subnets
  name                 = lower("sn-${var.spoke_vnet_name}-${each.value.subnet_name}")
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.subnet_address_prefix
  service_endpoints    = lookup(each.value, "service_endpoints", [])
  # Applicable to the subnets which used for Private link endpoints or services
  enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = lookup(each.value, "enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies", null)
  enforce_private_link_service_network_policies  = lookup(each.value, "enforce_private_link_service_network_policies", null)

  dynamic "delegation" {
  for_each = lookup(each.value, "delegation", false) != false ? [1] : []
  content {
    name = each.value.delegation.delegation_name
      service_delegation {
        name    = each.value.delegation.delegation_service
        actions = each.value.delegation.delegation_action
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And in the locals.tf file I am passing the values as follows

```
XXX_subnet = {
          subnet_name           = "XXX"
          subnet_address_prefix = ["00.000.00.00/00"]
          nsg_inbound_rules = [
            # [name, priority, direction, access, protocol, destination_port_range, source_address_prefix, destination_address_prefix]
            # To use defaults, use "" without adding any value and to use this subnet as a source or destination prefix.
          ]
          nsg_outbound_rules = [
            # [name, priority, direction, access, protocol, destination_port_range, source_address_prefix, destination_address_prefix]
            # To use defaults, use "" without adding any value and to use this subnet as a source or destination prefix.
          ]
          delegation = {
            name = ["XXX",]
            service_delegation = {
              name   = ["Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers",]
              actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",]
              }
          }
        }
```

But when I run a plan I get the following error

```
Error: Unsupported attribute
  on line 59, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "main":
  59:     name = each.value.delegation.delegation_name
    ├────────────────
    │ each.value.delegation is object with 2 attributes
This object does not have an attribute named "delegation_name".
Error: Unsupported attribute
  on line 61, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "main":
  61:         name    = each.value.delegation.delegation_service
    ├────────────────
    │ each.value.delegation is object with 2 attributes
This object does not have an attribute named "delegation_service".
Error: Unsupported attribute
  on line 62, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "main":
  62:         actions = each.value.delegation.delegation_action
    ├────────────────
    │ each.value.delegation is object with 2 attributes
This object does not have an attribute named "delegation_action".
```

Comment: What **exactly** is `var.subnets`?

Comment: @Marcin var.subnets is a list of subnets in locals.tf file and I have the following variable defined in the variables.tf file ```variable "subnets" {
  description = "For each subnet, create an object that contain fields"
  default     = {}
}```

Comment: I mean, actual value. Also please edit the question with new code, rather then adding it to comments.

Comment: @chris Did you mean to use locals instead of var.subnets?

Comment: I think instead of `each.value.xyz` it needs to be `delegation.value.xyz`

Comment: I think he can use the former syntax as the resource is created already with `for_each`.

Comment: @silent **delegation.value.xyz** did not work. Getting the following error **Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (number)**